# How to access a property in twig that begins with a hash

Tags: theming, 9

I'm trying to get to the name of a media file in twig. The name is located at:

```
mediaitem[0]->#values[name][x-default]
```

in the rendered entity passed into the template with `field_media_item|field_value`.

Comment: Preprocess it and get the field value through the API.

Comment: You may also consider using [twig_tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak).

Answer (score 1):

You can access hash properties in Twig `{{ foo['#bar'] }}`, but not the internal (protected) `'#values` table of an entity. Look in the [media entity](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21media%21src%21Entity%21Media.php/class/Media) for public methods starting with `get`.

In this case getName():

```
{{ media.getname }}
```

The question doesn't provide information about the context, but if it is for example a node then you can access media items like this:

```
{% for field_media_item in node.field_media %}
    {{ field_media_item.entity.getname }}
{% endfor %}
```

It's recommended to use a get method if the entity provides one, because they often contain extra logic. If you don't find a get method then access the field value directly:

```
{{ field_media_item.entity.name.value }}
```